# Drivers for hp chromebook "madoo" 14b cb0?

Tags: drivers, chromebook

Switched to debian and ran the weirdtreething script now sound is working

Comment: The previous comment links to a chromebook audio driver script that works best with Ubuntu 23.10 and later